# Unity 5 light reflection on the water surface

Tags: unity, water, reflection-rendering

How to adjust reflection in Unity 5 to show up it on the water surface. So I have few light elements in the scene. So I want my water pro to reflect this lights.

As example you can see red and yellow lights from the Shanghai's build on the water, that's what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

I've added water pro and setup flare:

[image]

Looks liker here some small reflection on the rect I market as red. But if comparing with real reflection it's more vertical reflection I've marked it as red well:

[image]

If you can see it unity example does not look natural. So if we compare distance from sun to the beach border on real photo, there is a huge sun line over the water surface, but there is not the same line on water pro in unity.

Here is a video link with what I did:
http://screencast.com/t/bq8Ocl24ZAJH

Comment: Are you using the [Unity 5 standard water assets](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-Water.html), and have you added a [Flare](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Flare.html) to use on your light sources?

Comment: @DMGregory yea I set up pro water and flare on my light, but there no reflection from point light for example

Comment: We'll need to see more details of your scene setup then. When I create a new scene and drop the WaterProDaytime or WaterProNighttime prefab into it along with a point light with a bright flare, I immediately see the flare reflected in the water.

Comment: @DMGregory, hm let me prepare screencast, thanks for help. I use 5.2 version if smth, maybe because of it.

Comment: @DMGregory, I've updated my question with few examples, so you can also watch my video http://screencast.com/t/bq8Ocl24ZAJH thanks for help

Comment: @DMGregory I fount this link http://blogs.unity3d.com/2011/01/11/standard-assets-update-part-one/ and this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8sVvs6R4WTs that seems it's possible, but without configuration.

Comment: I think the main difference here is the angle of your camera. You only get strongly stretched reflections when looking at a very shallow angle out along the water surface (ie. the camera's height above the water is much much smaller than the distance to the reflected object). I'm able to reproduce the image from the Unity example you link just by matching the camera angle, and looking out very flat along the water.

Comment: @DMGregory, I thought the same, but after that I've rotated camera and reposition it from the surface plane and then higher, so there is no effects like I've described still.

Comment: Your question inspired me to write a new water shader. It uses the same BRDF (for the specular term at least) that Unity's standard shader uses, and it is giving pretty good results, like what you require.

Comment: @EvilTak, ok that's awesome) cool thanks, can you post some details how to create it?) thanks

Comment: This what you're looking for? https://gyazo.com/20308cbd0a4454d3e7cb6d36accb5971 This uses the Blinn-Phong visibility term as it looks better for water. If you want, I can post the (incomplete and unoptimized) shader code.

Comment: @EvilTak how can I handle and adjust water advanced material?

Comment: @MatrosovAlexander what do you mean by that? Modify its settings? I haven't used it much to know what to do, but I do know that you can remove the waves by removing the Gerstner Displace script.

Comment: @EvilTak oh, actually I also found out that if we use WaterAdvanced instead of WaterProDayLight, we have needed reflection on surface, but I can't change any color of reflection settings. Yea I meant about some customazing shaders and etc

Comment: I can post the shader code here, you can go through it. Unity's Water4 doesn't include good support for point and spot lights, but my version uses light attenuation with shadows correctly.

Comment: @EvilTak, yea just post it cool, thank you, I wanted to know how can I create my own custom shader? can I create it in Maya for example and then exports as FBX? I mean when I create materials with all setting, will Unity read it?

Comment: @MatrosovAlexander no, that's not how shaders work in Unity. Shaders in Unity are Cg programs, a programming language. I'm on a phone so I don't have a link to post, but if you search for Unity shader tutorials or look up the Manual or Docs, you'll be able to understand how Unity uses shaders. Unity shaders and Maya/3ds max shaders are completely different, and can't be used in place of one another.

Comment: @EvilTak, man thanks for comments again) as I understood we can use Diffuse and Self illumination, so it's kind of shader I guess. If we export FBX then we can use a lot of stuff. http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-ImportObjectMax.html